# Declaring a usercontrol property as a static resource

Tags: wpf

I have a property defined within my usercontrol

```
private StaticInfoCollection _StaticInfoColl;
public StaticInfoCollection StaticInfoColl
{
    get { return _StaticInfoColl; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _StaticInfoColl) return;
        _StaticInfoColl = value;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to use this in the xaml.
However whenever I do declare the property as follows

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:Static.StaticInfoColl x:Key="SIColl" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The tag `Static.StaticInfoColl` does not exist in XML namespace `clr-namespace:AAA.Presentation`

Could someone help me on what I am doing wrong?

---

The name of the usercontrol is Static [x:Name]

```
<UserControl x:Class="AAA.Presentation.ucBrand"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:MBCL.Presentation"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="710" 
         d:DesignWidth="1025" 
         Height="710" 
         Width="1025" 
         x:Name="Static" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
```

I have a usercontrol with multiple buttons on them.
The buttons have a stackpanel within it as follows :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource appViewButton}" DataContext="{Binding}" >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock FontSize="11">View Products</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=FileDownloadDate,StringFormat='Last Uploaded : {0:dd-MMM-yyyy}'}"
                Style="{StaticResource tbUploadDate}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I have an entity `Info` and `InfoCollection`.
The button is bound to InfoCollection, based on the FileType I would like to select the appropriate FileDownloadDate and display it.

```
public class Info
{

    public Info(DataRow dr)
    {
        _FileType         = Util.HandleNull<string>(dr[AppConstants.FILE_TYPE]);
        _FileID           = Util.HandleNull<long?>(dr[AppConstants.FILEID]);
        _FileTypeDesc     = Util.HandleNull<string>(dr[AppConstants.CODE_DESC]);
        _FileDownloadDate = Util.HandleNull<DateTime>(dr[AppConstants.DOWNLOAD_DATE]);
    }

    private string _FileType;
    public string FileType
    {
        get { return _FileType; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _FileType)
                _FileType = value;
        }
    }

    private string _FileTypeDesc;
    public string FileTypeDesc
    {
        get { return _FileTypeDesc; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _FileTypeDesc)
                _FileTypeDesc = value;
        }
    }

    private long?   _FileID;
    public long?    FileID
    {
        get { return _FileID; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _FileID)
                _FileID = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime    _FileDownloadDate;
    public  DateTime    FileDownloadDate
    {
        get { return _FileDownloadDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _FileDownloadDate)
                _FileDownloadDate = value;
        }
    }

}

public class InfoCollection : ObservableCollection<Info>
{
    public InfoCollection(DataTable dtStaticInfo)
    {
        foreach (DataRow drSInfo in dtStaticInfo.Rows)
        {   
            this.Add(new StaticInfo(drSInfo));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your entire `Static` class.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. You can't create an instance of a property you can create an instance of an object, which has this(and more) properties. The "UserControl.Resources" section is for other classes or objects to use in your control, like Brushes, Animations, Styles, Templates etc. Also what is the "Static." in your xaml? A namespace? Thats the alias "local:" for. Please provide more details what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

- You have a UserControl (ucBrand).
- You have a class StaticInfoCollection
- You want to have a single instance of StaticInfoCollection used in multiple places within ucBrand, and you might want to access your StaticInfoCollection object in code as well.

If that's the case... you're close... but I'd do the following instead:

Define the instance of your StaticInfoCollection object in XAML.

```
<UserControl.Resources> 
    <local:StaticInfoCollection x:Key="SIColl" /> 
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then when you want to access your StaticInfoCollection object in your UserControl's code:

```
StaticInfoCollection staticInfoColl = (StaticInfoCollection)this.FindResource("SIColl");
```

Comment: Hi Scott,Thank you for the speedy response - local is defined as xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AAA.Presentation", however StaticInfoCollection is a property under ucBrand     [AAA.Presentation.ucBrand] and how do I xcreate a resource to point to the property.

Comment: 'StaticInfoCollection' appears to be a type. 'StaticInfoColl' is your property of that type. My suggestion was to remove the property, and instead create an instance of StaticInfoCollection (the type) as a resource. Then in code... instead of accessing your property 'StaticInfoColl', you can access it using 'this.FindResource(...)'. It all depends on what exactly you're trying to do with the instance of this class in your XAML however.

Comment: Can you explain what you are hoping to do with the property in XAML? (for example display its value as text The more I think about what you're tryin to do... the more I think you should simply bind to your property... and not actually create it as a resource.